# table.whitelist is working as case sensitive even after specifying quote.sql.identifiers=NEVER

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have used JDBC source connector to ingest data from oracle to kafka topics. I have kafka topics created in small letters so I have to specify `table.whitelist=table_name` (in small case). Since by default it takes everything in quotes so I have explicitly specified property in order to make it case insensitive `quote.sql.identifiers=NEVER` but, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using confluent platform.

You can set topic name using Transformation: [`ExtractTopic`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic). `ExtractTopic` transformation can take any message field an set its value as topic name.

In your use case you can add field with your topic name to JDBC Source connector `query` property (`SELECT ..., 'topicName' from ...`) and than with `ExtractTopic` set topic name